# state values is undefined intially even after being set

Tags: reactjs, react-select

The below function is onChange event for a react-select dropdown. The this.state.value(highlighted in Bold) is undefined only for the first time when the dropdown changes. Could someone provide input on the same.  However the state is set in the below else condition.

```
handleSelectChange(val,event) {
  var label;
if(val.map==undefined) {
  label = val["label"];
  this.setState({value:val}) ;
}
else{
  label = val["label"];
  this.setState({value:val}) ;
}
    this.setState({dropDownSelected:true},function(){
this.props.dropDownSelected(**this.state.value**);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 6):

That sounds painful but you need to know that `setState` works in an asynchronous way. That means after calling setState, `this.state` variable is not immediately changed. So, if you want to perform an action immediately after setting state on a state variable and then return a result. The callback will be useful.

Find the sample `setState` with callback function

```
this.setState({value:val}, function() {
    // Do something here 
  });
```

Cheers..!